# User deleted his own account and created a new one to win bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty, new-users, deleted-users

I suspect [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5590309/life-evader) is the same user as `user5515672`.

User `user5515672` [started a bounty a week ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672519/android-how-to-load-image-dynamically-from-server-by-its-name-from-sqlite) and after a couple of days disappeared (i.e. his account was deleted). Just yesterday a newly created account (3 days) just [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672519/android-how-to-load-image-dynamically-from-server-by-its-name-from-sqlite) that question.

As an evidence, in that answer you see sentences using pronoun "I". I don't accuse that user of committing illegal activity.

Just am curious whether those user are the same or not. If so, Is it illegal to create another account to win your own bounty?

Comment: Trial by meta rarely goes well.  If you suspect wrong doing, flag the post, explain the issue, and let the mods deal with it.  But you shouldn't take accusations to the community.  You don't want to see someone punished unfairly by the community if your guess was wrong.

Comment: If the user was trying to win their own bounty then wouldn't they have awarded it before deleting their account rather than just hoping to get the most highly up voted answer to get half the bounty? Even before Brad answered explaining he deleted the account it didn't look like an attempt at cheating the bounty system.

Comment: Just compare the fair English of that answer to the Nicholas Cage-ish Random capiTalizing Of The original USER.

Comment: Yes, All of you are right. However, I just can't understand what's the point of those down-votes? I asked a question and now got my answer and figured out I was wrong. Why downvotes?

Comment: [Voting on meta is different](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Down votes here can indicate disagreement (in addition to the usual reasons).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't believe this is the same user. I was the one who deleted the account that left the bounty, because it was a sock puppet of another (now suspended) account. I didn't invalidate the bounty because people had left good answers in an attempt to win it, and didn't want to cheat them of the system-awarded half bounty.

I've checked all the users involved and I see no connection between them. I think this is a legitimate account by a new user, leaving an answer to a bountied question. The use of "I" simply indicates that this is something they've done before in their own code.

As far as the more general question, yes, it is considered voting fraud to award bounties between multiple accounts that you control. We do step in for obvious cases like this and invalidate bounties or remove accounts as necessary. That doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: Thanks, you're right, however, it's just a bit weird for a newly joined user to _find_ (among this massive load of questions) an 8 days old answer. Isn't?

Comment: @HiI'mfrogatto - No. The entire point of putting a bounty on a question is that it gets more attention and is easier to find. That user answered yesterday and the bounty ended today. That would have put it near the top of the bounties list when sorting by which ones are ending soonest. It makes perfect sense that a new user, looking to get rep, would have seen that question.

Answer (score -10):

In the UK there's certainly no law against it :-)

But as it's a Q&A site - does it *really* make a difference as long as the question received a meaningful answer that's useful to the wider community? The point of a bounty is to generate more interest in a question so that it can receive a satisfying answer. It doesn't say anywhere that the answer **has** to come from someone else.

If it is a duplicate account - the individual is no better off, they've simply moved points from one account to another (And if the old account was deleted then they've actually lost even more points...).

It may be frustrating for other users but things like this will always follow with a points-based system. No-one was hurt so I think it's best to just let this one go. If it started to become a common occurrence then maybe some intervention or monitoring would be required.

Comment: Moving rep to a new account allows for the new account to vote and give the old account reputation in return.

Answer (score -17):

Think this is the sign of gelliousy at the end of day is Stack Overflow not about earning and learning from ones mistakes to product a better question and answer. If they deserve the bounty they should get it but if its a case of multple asking questions to get it then not so. But who is to determine the amount of questions asked in a day or a week def not yourself it up to the stack team to set those limits as a new commer I find this very type of thing for me not to like peer drivin sites.

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at here. Your answer seems kind of... Rambly to me. Can you edit to clarify what you mean exactly, and how it's relevant to the question here? I've read your answer several times and just really can't pull out what you're trying to say. (That might be why your answer is being downvoted.)

Comment: new that would happen 12 downvotes just cause a person cant spell the comunity needs to understand what delaxy is and get with the times gellious much

Comment: What is delaxy? gellious? Your misspelling caused your answer to be hard to understand, and you blamed the community? In addition of that, I really can't understand what you are trying to convey with this answer.